# How do I fix the dimension of the return value of flow from Image Generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use `fit_generator`. But I get the error

> Error when checking input: expected sequential_1_input to have 3
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (20, 28, 28, 1)

Here is the code:

```
data_flow = data_generator.flow(x_train, y_train,batch_size=20) 
generate = model.fit_generator(data_flow, steps_per_epoch=1400,epochs=10)
```

Each batch from the flow has output of `(20,28,28,1)`. But the `fit_generator` expects 3 dimensions. How can I reshape the return of flow function since it's a iterator yielding tuples.

Comment: Most likely you've erroneously defined the input shape of the first model layer. Might it be you've passed (28, 28) and not (28, 28, 1)?

Comment: The model works fine for regular fit method. It's only while using fit_generator.

Comment: I have already trained the model without data augmentation.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error, it works flawlessly using model's `fit` as well as `fit_generator` methods. I used this [keras mnist](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) code as a base. Just check your data once again, you're missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible ways to do it:

- If possible you can change the InputShape of your model to have three parameters like `[28,28,1]` to fit your data shape instead of two.
- you can change the shape of `x_train` and `y_train` before creating the generator

```py
x_train = tf.reshape(x_train, shape=[28,28]) # likewise for y_train
```

- `flow` returns an iterator, so one can use `map` to reshape its output (code not tested)

```py
# squeeze to remove the dimension with length 1
map(lambda x, y: tf.squeeze(x), y, data_flow) 
# otherwise one can use tf.reshape
map(lambda x, y: tf.reshape(x, shape=x.shape[0:-1]), y, data_flow)
```

Comment: data_generator.flow, according to keras documentation, needs input of range 4. So, I am not sure if I can change dimension of x_train.

Comment: My CNN model has input shape of (48,48,1). THe model worked fine for regular .fit method. The problem is only while using the .fit_generator.

Comment: @KiranShrestha, `fit_generator` accepts iterator. So after reshaping `data_flow=map(lambda x, y: tf.squeeze(x), y, data_flow)`, you can pass the new generator to `fit_generator`